# using ModelForm Wizards with User Image Upload - can't get user.PK

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-formwizard

I've been trying to create a photo upload system that allows users to upload an image and then write in a title and comment for that image. I was originally using a ModelForm when I made the image upload functionality but switched to a Form Wizard for the upload & comment functionality based on previous stackoverflow answers. I'm really confused on getting my site's user id system to work with this approach (I keep getting the error user id cannot be null when I attempt to upload pictures) and can't find any good resources -- any suggestions on whether this approach is valid and how I can fix the user_id issue?

Views.py:

```
def showScrapbookPage(request,userID):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        image = ImageUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        user = User.objects.get(pk=userID)
        if image.is_valid():
            image.save()
    scrapbook_gen = Pictures.objects
    url = Pictures.objects.filter(user=User.objects.get(pk=userID))
    return render(request, 'scrapbook/scrapbook.html', {'scrapbook_gen':scrapbook_gen, 'url':url, 'form': ImageUploadForm(),'userID':userID})


class PhotoWizard(SessionWizardView):
    file_storage = FileSystemStorage(location = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, ''))
    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        do_something_with_the_form_data(form_list)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/page-to-redirect-to-when-done/')
```

Models.py:

```
class Pictures(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'scrapbook_uploads', default = 'static/scrapbook/images/no_pic_uploaded.jpg');
    date = models.DateTimeField('date published', auto_now=True)
    caption = models.TextField(blank = True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank = True) #New
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.caption
```

Forms.py:

```
class ImageUploadForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Pictures
        fields = ['picture']
        user = ['userID']

class TitleCommentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Pictures
        field = ["caption", "title"]
```

urls:

```
url(r'^(?P<userID>[-\w]+)/scrapbook/',views.showScrapbookPage, name='showScrapbook'),
url(r'^contact/$', PhotoWizard.as_view([ImageUploadForm, TitleCommentForm])),
```

Relevant section in template:

```
{% load i18n %}

{% block head %}
{{ wizard.form.media }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<p>Step {{ wizard.steps.step1 }} of {{ wizard.steps.count }}</p>
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<table>
{{ wizard.management_form }}
{% if wizard.form.forms %}
    {{ wizard.form.management_form }}
    {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
        {{ form }}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    {{ wizard.form }}
{% endif %}

</table>
{% if wizard.steps.prev %}
<button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.first }}">{% trans "first step" %}</button>
<button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}">{% trans "prev step" %}</button>
{% endif %}
<input type="submit" value="{% trans "submit" %}"/>
</form>
{% endblock %}

 <!--Grid -->
  <div id='frame'>
    <table id = "frame-table">
        <tr>
          <td id = "left">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" alt = "left"></span>
          </td>
          <td id = "right">
            <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" alt = "right"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    <img id = "main" src="" alt=""/>
  </div>
  <div id = "wrapper" class="showpiece">
    <ul id = "portfolio">
      {% for x in url %}
      {{ x.picture }}
      <li><img src = '{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ x.picture }}' ></li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Completely remove your added `UserID` stuff and use `user = request.user`instead in your views.